# AWK / at least two 'a' characters but no 'u' characters

Tags: awk

I've written down the following AWK script to list the files that have at least two 'a' letters and no 'u' letter in their full path.

```
BEGIN {}

{
if ( (match($1, "^.*[a].*[a]+$") ) )
print $1
}

END{}
```

Right now, as you can, the script is unable to eliminate 'u' letter. What modification must I perform to get what I want?

P.S. it reads the file names with their full paths from a file called "data" created separately via the following command.

```
find / -name '*' > data
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using bash, you can do this without external tools like sed, awk or find.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

for filename in **/*a*a*; do
  [[ "$filename" =~ u ]] || echo "$filename"
done
```

If this absolutely has to be awk, I would use:

```
awk '/a.*a/ && ! /u/' data
```

**UPDATE:**

Per gniourf_gniourf's polite admonishment, you may get better performance using pathname expansion (globs) instead of a regexp.  Here's a (non-scientific) benchmark:

```
$ rm -f file
$ for (( i=1000000; i-- ; )); do echo u >> file; done
$ time bash -c 'while read i; do [[ $i = *u* ]]; done < file'

real    0m8.291s
user    0m6.570s
sys     0m1.717s
$ time bash -c 'while read i; do [[ $i =~ u ]]; done < file'

real    0m10.416s
user    0m8.676s
sys     0m1.735s
```

The "user" line is the one we're interested in.

This makes it appear as if the fileglob runs about 30% faster than the regex, testing a million records with positive results.

Oddly, there isn't so much of an improvement when tests fail:

```
$ time bash -c 'while read i; do [[ $i = *a* ]]; done < file'

real    0m8.244s
user    0m6.601s
sys     0m1.639s
$ time bash -c 'while read i; do [[ $i =~ a ]]; done < file'

real    0m9.757s
user    0m8.121s
sys     0m1.630s
```

This is only a 23% speed improvement on these million tests.  If this sort of optimization of shell scripts is important (because you're running millions of tests and don't feel that you have any CPU cycles to spare), then please do consider gniourf_gniourf's suggestion when your course moves on from awk to bash.

Comment: I must use AWK as I described. Assignment requires it like that.

Comment: That's not what your question indicated.

Comment: @CanSürmeli - added an awk solution for you.  I don't think you'll find any that are more compact.  (Yes, you can remove whitespace from it.)

Comment: +1 for the awk solution which I'm sure is what the OPs teacher is looking for.

Comment: Don't use a regex in your bash statement, it's useless, slow and retarded. A glob is enough in this case: `[[ "$filename" = *u* ]]`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - added some benchmark analysis.  While you're absolutely right, regexp evaluation is slower than pathname expansion, I think that given the degree of difference, I'm not sure I'd categorize regexps as "useless".  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Please use the following benchmark instead: `time for i in {1..1000000}; do [[ abc = *b* ]]; done` v.s. `time for i in {1..1000000}; do [[ abc =~ b ]]; done`.

Comment: Btw, when reading my previous comment, I notice it's not really polite. I didn't notice when I wrote it, and please accept my apologies (really my point was not to offend anyone!). Just I strongly believe that regexps are not suited when useless. Also, it is not because scripting is not meant to be speed critical that we, script writers, must do our best to use the most inefficient methods. `;-)`

Comment: If I try your solution it works fine but if I paste the /a.*a/ && ! /u/ part into my AWk file, in between double quotes, it doesn't generate anything. What the problem here? I'm executing the AWK file like awk -f file.awk data

Comment: @CanSürmeli "_if I paste the /a.*a/ && ! /u/ part into my AWk file, in between double quotes..._". Why on earth would you do that? Why would you think it would work?

Comment: @EdMorton Because I need an AWK file doing what I asked

Comment: @CanSürmeli - Try using single quotes, as my example did. Also, if you are using `tcsh` instead of `bash`, then the exclamation point may be getting interpreted as a history reference regardless of quotes. To avoid this, use a different shell (`sh` for example).

Answer (score 3):

"list the files that have at least two 'a' letters and no 'u' letter in their full path":

```
find / -type f -path "*a*a*" ! -path "*u*" > data
```

Comment: I must use AWK as I described. Assignment requires it like that.

Comment: **+1**.  Good to see all-in-one solutions.

Comment: @CanSürmeli: Please see ghoti's updated answer. It should be the accepted answer given your list of filenames. That said, it would still be better to avoid finding the error-some filenames in the first place.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I'm asking this just because I couldn't figure it out myself.

Answer (score 3):

How about using directly the find options for this task, so as to avoid your file `data` altogether?

```
find / -name '*a*a*' -not -name '*u*'
```

Now, if you really need your file `data`, then a `sed` should be enough:

```
sed -n '/a.*a/{/u/!p}' data
```

If you really want to use `awk`:

```
awk '/a.*a/ { if ($LINE !~ /u/) print ; }' data
```

And for a pure bash version:

```
while read -r file; do
    if [[ "$file" = *a*a* ]] && [[ "$file" != *u* ]]; then 
        echo "$file"
    fi
done < data
```

And for a pure bash version without the `data` file at all and without any `find` command, using globs:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob

for file in /**/*a*a*; do
    if [[ "$file" != *u* ]]; then
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
```

This last version will be much slower than the other ones if you have lots of files (which is generally the case in `/`). It will slurp all the file names, and then echo them. The solution with the `find` is the best as the file names will be echoed (and/or processed) as they are found.

Hope this helps!